# using mjpeg with basic authentication in cordovaapp

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, basic-authentication, mjpeg

To get a motionjpeg stream from a ip camerIn a native App I would add a RequestHeader to the GET-Request containing the credentials. In an ajax-call I also can append headers to get a single image.

But to show continuous images the only way seem to be using

```
<img src="url_to_mpjeg">
```

The webui of the camera is successfully doing the  GET-call like this:
1. you enter the ui with a request to index.html, which needs credentials
2. any further request (like the  GET request) automatically have the basic authentication injected by the browser

So I also tried calling another URL of the camera with authentication-header in advanced but this doesn't work in cordova. Every single request needs a manual authentication in the header, nothing is magically added to the headerfields.

I think the reason why it automatically works in the camera webui is because the cameras index.html and further requests are all from the same origin, but in my cordovaapp, the UI is coming from file://local somewhere.

Is there a way in javascript to call a jpeg stream with basic authentication?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the chromium team, [images credentials does not work anymore](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=305215)
If you want to load some stream as mjpg or img with basic auth protected url use iframe instead.

`<iframe src="you_stream_link"></iframe>`